# How to do a POST inside a JSP or Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

I need to do a http post call to an external URL from my servlet. And I need to add some custom http headers too to the message. Is this possible ? please provide me a guidance.

Comment: No. You have mistaken my question. I need to do a HTTP POST call to third party URL from my Servlet in my web app.

Comment: Yes, I know. You're instead mistaking me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try apache HttpClient library.